# Calculating Occupancy in hospital from dates with time.

Tags: r, date, tidyverse

I am looking to calculate occupancy in emergency department (ED) with tidyverse. Occupancy is understood here in this particular problem as Admitted but did not leave the hospital within the same hour they were admitted. A clearer example would be: if I came at ED at 12:00:00 and did not leave within the hour I was admitted, then I am occupying the bospital. So for this I need to create a new column Occupancy. (A little insight to give - I want to plot occupancy by hour of the day. Yet I know how to plot this, but do not know how to calculate occupancy. Thus no need for you to be bogged down on this issue as I am giving you an insight of my project). What I need though is to learn how to calculate occupancy from the table I have bellow. Please do help.

I have ID, Admission = Adm and Disc = Discharges.

```
ID = c(101, 102,103, 104, 105, 106, 107)

Adm = as.POSIXct(c("2012-01-12 00:52:00", "2012-01-12 00:55:00", "2012-02-12 
                    01:35:00", "2012-02-12 03:24:00", "2012-02-12 04:24:00", 
                   "2012-02-12 05:24:00", "2012-02-12 05:28:00"))

Disc = as.POSIXct(c("2012-01-12 02:00:00", "2012-01-12 02:59:00", "2012-01-12 
                     03:01:00", "2012-01-12 05:01:00", "2012-01-12 06:01:00", 
                    "2012-01-12 08:01:00", "2012-01-12 08:01:00"))

df = data.frame(ID, Adm, Disc)
```

I have extracted the hour from the Admission. So that I can use the new column for calculating the occupancy - understood at the problem at hand as Admitted but were not discharged within the hour the patients were admitted. To remind you, I want to do this with tidyverse library

```
df_hour <- df %>%
  mutate(Hour_Adm = lubridate::hour(as.POSIXct(Adm, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")))
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you entered wrong Adm and Disc dates for subjects 2,3,4,5, and 6. I already made an edit for the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic is to add 1 hour (i.e. `60*60` seconds) to `Adm` time (which is of `POSIXct` type) and compare it with `Disc` time.

`First` & `last` is added for cases wherein multiple rows are there for an `ID`. Then the earliest `Adm` and latest `Disc` time will only be considered per `ID`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(occupancy = ifelse(last(Disc) > first(Adm) + 60*60, 1, 0))
```

which gives

```
     ID Adm                 Disc                occupancy
  <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>                  <dbl>
1   101 2012-01-12 00:52:00 2012-01-12 02:00:00      1.00
2   102 2012-01-12 00:55:00 2012-01-12 02:59:00      1.00
3   103 2012-02-12 01:35:00 2012-01-12 03:01:00      0   
4   104 2012-02-12 03:24:00 2012-01-12 05:01:00      0   
5   105 2012-02-12 04:24:00 2012-01-12 06:01:00      0   
6   106 2012-02-12 05:24:00 2012-01-12 08:01:00      0   
7   107 2012-02-12 05:28:00 2012-01-12 08:01:00      0
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107), Adm = structure(c(1326309720, 
1326309900, 1328990700, 1328997240, 1329000840, 1329004440, 1329004680
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Disc = structure(c(1326313800, 
1326317340, 1326317460, 1326324660, 1326328260, 1326335460, 1326335460
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Adm", "Disc"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thank you Prem. Can you explain this part - ifelse(last(Disc) > first(Adm) + 60*60, please? I want to double check my knowledge on what this code does.

Comment: thank you a lot Prem. Can you please explain this little part of your code: last(Disc) > first(Adm) + 60*60

Comment: Hello Prem, actually I am wrong to say it helped. it did not because it is the length of stay is different than Occupancy. Actually I want to check how many patients are in the hospital at a given time. In my project is every hour of the day, from 00 to 23:00.

Comment: Hello Prem, actually I am wrong to say it helped. it did not because it is the length of stay is different than Occupancy. Actually I want to check how many patients are in the hospital at a given time. In my project is every hour of the day, from 00 to 23:00.

Comment: Now it's an entirely different problem so I would suggest to start a new question. But don't forget to mention sample data & desired output.

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
       mutate(`Stay In (Hours)` = hour(Disc) - hour(Adm), Occupancy = ifelse(hour(Disc) - hour(Adm) > 1, 1, 0)) 
       %>% ungroup()

#But notice that `hour` consider the hour's part of the time only as shown below, which may lead to misleading results:
hour(as.POSIXct(c("2012-01-12 01:40:00"))) - hour(as.POSIXct(c("2012-01-12 00:50:00")))
[1] 1
```

The correct answer I hope so:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
       mutate(`Stay In (Hours)` = round(difftime(Disc, Adm, units='hours'),2), 
               Occupancy = ifelse(difftime(Disc, Adm, units='hours') > 1, 1, 0)) %>% 
       ungroup()

  # A tibble: 7 x 5
     ID     Adm                Disc           `Stay In (Hours)`      Occupancy
    <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>               <time>                <dbl>
1   101 2012-01-12 00:52:00 2012-01-12 02:00:00     1.13                  1.00
2   102 2012-01-12 00:55:00 2012-01-12 02:59:00     2.07                  1.00
3   103 2012-01-12 01:35:00 2012-02-12 03:01:00    745.43                 1.00
4   104 2012-01-12 03:24:00 2012-02-12 05:01:00    745.62                 1.00
5   105 2012-01-12 04:24:00 2012-02-12 06:01:00    745.62                 1.00
6   106 2012-01-12 05:24:00 2012-02-12 08:01:00    746.62                 1.00
7   107 2012-01-12 05:28:00 2012-02-12 08:01:00    746.55                 1.00
```

Comment: thank you a lot A.Suliman. One more question that is not related to this question is how I can print out the dataframe on stackoverflow so that I can visually see how the data looks like.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly. You can use `dput(df)` then copy paste the output of `dput(df)` and added to your question in SO.

Comment: Hello A Suliman, apparently I am wrong to say it helped. Actually it did not because it is the length of stay is different than Occupancy. Actually I want to check how many patients are in the hospital at a given time. In my project is every hour of the day, from 00 to 23:00.