# Calculating the Average Occupancy with tidyverse only

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I am calculating the average Arrivals and average Occupancy across hours of the day with tidyverse only.

Yet, the example above does not actually calculate the average occupancy but rather the number of people at certain time.

Yet, if I have a person coming, lets say in a hospital, at Emergency department, arriving on 10th of December, 2018 at 10 am and leaves second day at 7:45. That means the Occupancy is of a value of 1.00 patient treated from 10am all the way to 7am next day(not including 8 am and 9 am). And averaging the Occupancy over two dates, that means, Occupancy is 0.5 for all the hours from 10am the date the patient arrived, to 7 am, when the patient was discharged, on the next day, excluding 8am and 9am  (mean is 0). That is the same for Arrivals, with the difference that it calculates only for the time a patient has arrived and not for all the hours they stay. This is the difference between the Occupancy and Arrivals, which seems that all answers given in my previous help requests has solved the Arrivals averages and not the Occupancy, although I have requested the Averaged Occupancy.

Here is one example that I tried to solve in the past.

[Calculating Occupancy in hospital from dates with time.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926422/calculating-occupancy-in-hospital-from-dates-with-time)

Which I reproduce bellow.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107), Adm = 
       structure(c(1326309720, 1326309900, 1328990700, 1328997240, 
                   1329000840, 1329004440, 1329004680), 
       class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Disc = 
       structure(c(1326313800, 1326317340, 1326317460, 1326324660, 
                   1326328260, 1 326335460, 1326335460), 
       class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), 
       .Names = c("ID", "Adm", "Disc"),  
       row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(occupancy = ifelse(last(Disc) > first(Adm) + 60*60, 1, 0))
```

Here is a minimalist example, which is a reproducible data type I have, for the sake of simplicity. Yet, cannot disclose any data from original data for data protection reasons.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 101:103, 
                    `Admissions <- as.POSIXct(c("2018-12-10 09:30:00", 
                                     "2018-12-10 10:15:00", 
                                     "2018-12-11 08:05:00"), 
                                  tz =  "Europe/London")` = 
                    structure(c(1544434200, 1544436900, 1544519100), 
                    class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), 
                    tzone = "Europe/London"), 
                    `Discharges <- as.POSIXct(c("2018-12-10 12:30:00", 
                                      "2018-12-11 07:45:00", 
                                      "2018-12-11 09:05-00"),             
                                   tz = "Europe/London")` = 
                   structure(c(1544445000, 1544514300, 1544519100), 
                   class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), 
                   tzone = "Europe/London")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
                   class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And the expected output is:

```
output <- structure(list(
       Hour = 0:23, 
       Average_arrivals = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 
                            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
       Average_occ = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 
                       1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
                       0.5, 0.5)), 
       row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
       spec = structure(list(cols = list(X1 = 
       structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), 
       Hour = structure(list(), class =c("collector_integer","collector")),
       Average_arrivals = structure(list(), 
                          class = c("collector_double", "collector")), 
       Average_occ = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                 "collector"))), 
                     default = structure(list(), 
                     class = c("collector_guess","collector"))), 
                     class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: How do you intend to summarize ID 103, who has a discharge at the same moment as arrival?

Comment: updated the mistake .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using the tidyverse. First I convert to long format using `gather`, and then create a "change" column that is +1 for admissions and -1 for discharges.

Then I sum this up by hour (could be more granular, like "5 minutes" if desired) and add all the unmentioned hours by using `padr:pad` (I also add extra hours on the back to make it a full set of 48 hours).

Occupancy is then the cumulative sum of the changes. By grouping by hour across the 2 days, we can get Average_arrivals and Average_occ.

Data

```
# Note, I could not load the sample data as provided, as the variable
#   names included the desired data as text.
df <- data.frame(ID = 101:103,
                 Admissions = as.POSIXct(c("2018-12-10 09:30:00", 
                    "2018-12-10 10:15:00", "2018-12-11 08:05:00")),
                 Discharges = as.POSIXct(c("2018-12-10 12:30:00", 
                    "2018-12-11 07:45:00", "2018-12-11 09:05:00")))
```

Solution

```
df_flat <- df %>%
  gather(status, time, Admissions:Discharges) %>%
  mutate(change = if_else(status == "Admissions", 1, -1)) %>%
  group_by(time_hr = lubridate::floor_date(time, "1 hour")) %>%
  summarize(arrivals = sum(status == "Admissions"),
            change = sum(change)) %>%
  # Here, adding add'l rows so all hours have 2 instances
  padr::pad(end_val = min(.$time_hr) + dhours(47)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(arrivals = 0, change = 0)) %>%
  mutate(occupancy = cumsum(change))

output <- df_flat %>%
  group_by(hour(time_hr)) %>%
  summarize(Average_arrivals = mean(arrivals),
            Average_occ = mean(occupancy))
```

Output

```
output
# A tibble: 24 x 3
# hour Average_arrivals Average_occ
# <int>            <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1     0              0           0.5
# 2     1              0           0.5
# 3     2              0           0.5
# 4     3              0           0.5
# 5     4              0           0.5
# 6     5              0           0.5
# 7     6              0           0.5
# 8     7              0           0  
# 9     8              0.5         0.5
# 10    9              0.5         0.5
```

Comment: hank you for this. It worked yet I am not entirely understanding this line:    
    `padr::pad(end_val = min(.$time_hr) + dhours(47)) `                                                                                                 
 what min does ? and what if I have hours over 6 months, what do I pass within the dhour component?

Comment: `padr:pad()` is handy for time series: it fills in all the "unmentioned" elements in a time series. In this case I'm specifying that I want the sequence to continue to a point 47 hours after the minimum hour, i.e. 48 hours total, so that the averages are calculated across two complete days. If the time series is very long, or part of an ongoing operation, it might be simplest to leave that term out and just use the time range of the data as is.

Comment: I actually need that sequence since in general, the averages should be across the fixed sequence. That assures that if we have an hour left for example, then that ‘padr::pad(end_val (min(.$time_hour) + dhours(47))’ fillss the missing hours in that sequence, getting the right averages. I did play dhours function and did put 2400 for the sequence i need. Yet, was wondering whether there is different way of creating that sequence, allowing more flexibility having in mind this will be part of a function woth different components. And if someone else wants to use that fixed function it wont work

Comment: Probably simplest to precalculate by figuring out the ranges you want. Depending on how you want that to work, that could be something like: `min_hour <- floor_date(min(time), "1 day")); max_hour <- ceiling_date(max(time), "1 day"))` and then feeding those into `padr::pad(start_val = mon_hour, end_val = max_hour)`.  I think the trick is to decide a good amount of time that represents the period when data "could have occurred but didn't," otherwise you might inadvertently dilute `Average_arrivals`.

Comment: Jon Spring - thank you a lot for your help. Very elegant. I am actually writing a library for CRAN repository and your help with this particular problem enables me to bring padr libary into other issues. Thanks!